# JavaScript regular expression to replace HTML anchors

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I got a HTML string and from this I want to convert some special a tags to something else. I need this for a TinyMCE plugin. I tried to change Wordpress wpgallery plugin.

For example: These are in HTML string

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> 
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="#" rel='special' title='link cat_id="4" content_id="5" content_slug="Slug 1"'>Some where else</a>
```

Here I have to find special link one and convert it to something else from it's title value 
like:

```
{link cat_id="4" content_id="5" content_slug="Slug 1"}
```

i need return value like this to insert it into MySQL

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> 
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
{link cat_id="4" content_id="5" content_slug="Slug 1"}
```

I tried this

```
function getAttr(s, n) {
            n = new RegExp(n + '="([^"]+)"', 'g').exec(s);
            return n ? tinymce.DOM.decode(n[1]) : '';
        };

return co.replace(/[^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>)/g, function(a,im) {
var cls = getAttr(im, 'rel');
   if ( cls.indexOf('special') != -1 )
       return '{'+tinymce.trim(getAttr(im, 'title'))+'}';

   return a;
});
```

this

```
/[^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>)/g
```

does not find tags with `rel` eq to 'special' but all the others.

Comment: Try this: [^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)" ([\S]*=.*(\ )*)*>([^<]+)<\/a>)

Comment: i need this regexp for tinymce plugin.This works for onBeforeSetContent but not with onPostProcess. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into the DOMDocument and related classes.  They are much better at parsing HTML than a homebrewed regex solution would be.

You can create a DOMdocument using your supplied markup, execute getElementsByTagName to get all the hyperlinks, scan their attributes for a rel attribute with the value of special, and then take the appropriate action.